# ¿Cómo suprimir el texto que hay entre parántesis?

Tags: php

¿Qué puedo usar para suprimir los textos entre paréntesis? Por ejemplo...

```
(I Saw) The Sign               // Devuelva  The Sign 
The Sign (I Saw)               // Devuelva  The Sign
(I Saw) The Sign (I Saw)       // Devuelva  The Sign
The Sign                       // Devuelva  The Sign
```

Con esto logré sacarlo si está al final, ejemplo "The Sign (I Saw)"

```
function texto_limpio($texto) {
       $buscar = '(';
       $posicion_parentesis = strpos($texto, $buscar);
       if (!$posicion_parentesis) {
           return $texto;
       } else {
           return substr($texto, 0, $posicion_parentesis);
       }
   }
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto y me voy perdiendo mientras avanzo, cualquier dato me sera de ayuda... desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: ¿paramétro o método? podrías usar expresiones una expresión regular, pero necesitaría más información de las posibles entradas que podes tener.

Comment: Hola Issca, las entradas llegan con o sin parentesis, antes le suprimo todo tipo de símbolo que me pueda traer problemas por ejemplo '´' => '',  '\'' => '',  ',' => '', '!' => '', '-' => '', '?' => '', '´' => '',  '.' => '' tratando de dejar el texto lo mas plano posible

Comment: ¿Se puede dar el caso que te aparezca una entrada como _(I (Saw) Other) The Sign_? Es decir, ¿pueden aparecer parentesis dentro de otros? ¿Y los parentesis están siempre balanceados? Si no es el caso la respuesta de @aeportugal sirve.

Comment: No, paréntesis dentro de otros no, a lo sumo "The Sign (texto)(texto)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es un buen caso para usar expresiones regulares:

```
$clean = preg_replace('/\([^)]+\)/','', '(I Saw) The Sign');
```

Habrán casos que quedan espacios a uno o ambos los lados. Para eliminarlos debes usar `trim`.

```
$clean = trim($clean);
```

Pero si tienes que hacerlo de forma más manual, esta función encuentra todas las posibles palabras entre dos paréntesis, y los reemplaza por un caracter vacío. Hace uno cada vez, por eso un `while()` hasta que ya no encuentre más coincidencias (..).

```
<?php
function texto_limpio($texto) {
    while(True) {
        $p1 = strpos($texto, '(');
        $p2 = strpos($texto, ')', $p1);
        if(($p1 !== false) and $p2) {
            $offset = $p2 - $p1 + 1;
            $substr = substr($texto, $p1, $offset);
            $texto = str_replace($substr, '', $texto);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return trim($texto);
}

echo texto_limpio('(I Saw) The Sign (I Saw)'); // The Sign
```

- Si preguntas por qué en el `if` se evalúa `$p1 == false` y `$p2` de foma diferente. Es porque el paréntesis '`(`' pudiera ir en la posición `0` del texto, que también PHP [evalúa como false](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php). Por lo que omitiría un texto que empiece en paréntesis.

[Editado] Se modificó la línea `$p2 = strpos($texto, ')');` por `$p2 = strpos($texto, ')', $p1);` lo cual significa que buscará el paréntesis de cierre a partir de encontrar el de apertura. Como estaba originalmente el script fallaba si la frase empieza con cierre de paréntesis, por ejemplo: `")The Sign (I Saw)"`

Comment: se podría usar `\ ?` o `\ *` en la expresión regular para borrar los espacios y evitar hacer `trim`, dejando la expresión regular en `\ ?\([^)]+\)\ ?` o `\ *\([^)]+\)\ *`, según sea el caso.

Comment: Ni bien salga del trabajo lo probaré y comentaré!

Comment: Llevaba 3 días con esto, los códigos funcionaron a la perfección... Por el momento usare function porque creo entenderlo mejor, por el momento las expresiones regulares es chino para mi

Comment: Agregué un pequeño ajuste a la función que corrige un fallo si la frase empieza con cierre de paréntesis @Fabricio